# How to add multi compiler parameters to meson.build

Tags: vala, ninja, meson-build

Normally I use this to compile one of my vala code:
`valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 -X -lm %f`

---

Now I try meson/ninja,

```
meson build --prefix=/usr
```

Then I edit the meson.build, add two lines. (After search a lot)

```
    link_args : '-X',
    link_args : '-lm',
```

The entire part is

```
executable(
    meson.project_name(),
    'src/Application.vala',
    dependencies: [
        dependency('gtk+-3.0')
    ],
    link_args : '-X',
    link_args : '-lm',
    install: true
)
```

ninja passed now, but it says:

```
meson.build:5: WARNING: Keyword argument "link_args" defined multiple times.
WARNING: This will be an error in future Meson releases.
```

So How to add multi compiler parameters correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to use an array

```
executable(
    meson.project_name(),
    'src/Application.vala',
    dependencies: [
        dependency('gtk+-3.0')
    ],
    link_args : ['-X', '-lm',],   # <- here
    install: true
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this instead, in the dependency section

```
meson.get_compiler('c').find_library('m', required: false),
```

That should add math library linkage for you.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand the name of the library -> 'm'. If I want use `--pkg librsvg-2.0`, how can I find the name?

Comment: The name of the library `m` refer to the math library which is part of libc. Packages could be added by the `dependency ()` function in your `meson.build` file. for example `dependency ('librsvg-2.0'),`